# How to uniquefy a list of dicts based on percentage similarity of a value in the dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, unique, similarity

I have a list of dicts that have a property that may be duplicate or similar to other dicts in the list. I'd like to use a similarity comparison function to uniquify this list. If any of the dicts have a value that is similar within a certain percentage of each other for the key "greeting", only one should be kept.

For example in this list, I want only one of the 'hello world' to remain:

```
list = [{"greeting":"HELLO WORLD!", ...}, {"greeting":"Hello Mars", ...}, {"greeting":"Hello World!!!", ...}, {"greeting":"hello world", ...}]
```

After uniquifying, the result would be:

```
list = [{"greeting":"HELLO WORLD!", ...}, {"greeting":"Hello Mars", ...}
```

All other dicts with similar greetings should be removed from the list.
It doesn't matter which of the similar dicts are kept.

Here is a function by [Nadia Alramli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1471603/192298):

```
def similar(seq1, seq2):
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=seq1.lower(), b=seq2.lower()).ratio() > 0.9
```

Comment: Do all the dictionaries contain the same keys ?

Comment: yes, but only the value of the greeting key is the one to be used for uniquify.

Comment: What do you want the resulting structure to look like?  All of your `dict`s have a single entry.  Is this typical?

Comment: @robert The dicts will have other entries, the example is oversimplified. But all the dicts have an equal number of entries and same keys. The structure should remain the same just with duplicate entries removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your function that determines uniqueness, you can do this:

```
import difflib

def similar(seq1, seq2):
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=seq1.lower(), b=seq2.lower()).ratio() > 0.9

def unique(mylist, keys):
    temp = mylist[:]
    for d in mylist:
        temp.pop(0)
        [d2.pop(i) for i in keys if d.has_key(i)
         for d2 in temp if d2.has_key(i) and similar(d[i], d2[i])] 
    return mylist
```

note that this will modify your dictionaries in place:

```
mylist = [{"greeting":"HELLO WORLD!"}, {"greeting":"Hello Mars"}, {"greeting":"Hello World!!!"}, {"greeting":"hello world"}]
unique(mylist, ['greeting'])

print mylist
```

Output:

```
[{'greeting': 'HELLO WORLD!'}, {'greeting': 'Hello Mars'}, {}, {}]
```

Comment: This would work but the dicts will have other entries that should not be checked, only the values for the "greeting" should be checked. In the example I put only one entry in each dict for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @Chad: so? Just compare the `greeting` values only.

Comment: I edited it to pass the keys you want to check, also you might wanna get rid of the list comprehension and do it as `for` loops instead for clarity.

Comment: @Amr, thanks, this works great. any way to delete the whole dict if it has a duplicate greeting value?

Comment: by delete do you mean removing the dictionary from the list, or making the dictionary empty ?

Comment: removing the dict from the list