# Is there any method in Django or Python For prediction?

Tags: python, django

Example if user type http://myurl.com/arti

it will redirect to 404 page where
i present url like

/article
(simmilar kind of Links)

Comment: @Efazati - I beg to disagree - furthermore, your comment is a bit irrelevant (he is talking about 404 page!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a catch-all URL, e.g. put `url(r"^(.*)$"` as your last entry in `urls.py` and then use some [string similarity measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures) to find a likely url. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471153/string-similarity-metrics-in-python) question for examples. Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison) for more of them.

Or perhaps just a simple `startswith()` loop over known urls will do?

Your view *probably* should return a response with a redirect (result code `302` or `303`) if there is a single match - and if there are none (or multiple) a `404` page with list of possible matches is the way to go.

Comment: @SundarNatrajAmancharla see the links above. If you are looking for someone to write the code for you, better head over to [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)