# Use Regular Expressions (or another python module) to compare text/characters?

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

Let's say that my program receives an input such as a string of characters that has any type of character.  For example, 'Bob's Bagel Shop'. Then it gets another string that says 'Fred's Bagel Store'. How can I use regular expressions or some other module in python to compare these and have my program tell me if at least 5 (or any number I want) of the characters are the same *anywhere in the string*, but all *in the same order*, such as the word 'Bagel'?

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be useful to simply compare how many words are the same? It would be much much more efficient than testing for any five characters!

Comment: @BillyMoon The problem is...these are usually business names (like McDonald's or something haha)...so it could have characters in it..but yes, it would probably be simpler.

Comment: you could use regex to determine what you consider a word to be (including special characters etc...), and then simply check each word in the first string against each word in the second.

Comment: `sBagelS`  should be the longest same string for this example?

Comment: Uh...yeah... 's Bagel S' would be it I guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a Python standard library class [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) that will help to solve your problem. Here's a code sample:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

s1 = "Bob's Bagel Shop"
s2 = "Bill's Bagel Shop"

matcher = SequenceMatcher(a=s1, b=s2)
match = matcher.find_longest_match(0, len(s1), 0, len(s2))
```

Result:

```
Match(a=3, b=4, size=13)  # value that 'match' variable holds
```

The result shows that both string has equal substring with 13 characters length (starting from 3-rd char in first string and 4-th char in second string).

You can use this match result object to get its fields as values:

```
match.size  # 13
match.a     # 3
match.b     # 4
```

Comment: How can I get the 'size' from the output? I need that number.

Comment: @MarcusJohnson Updated the answer to show how to receive members of Match object.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `itetools.combinations` and then use `intersection` of sets to find out matching characters from both strings:

```
from itertools import combinations
str1="Bob's Bagel Shop"
str2="Fred's Bagel Store"

def combi(strs):
    chars=''.join(strs.split())
    lis=[]
    for x in range(1,len(chars)):
        for y in combinations(chars,x):
            if ''.join(y) in chars:
                lis.append(''.join(y))
    return lis           


lis1=combi(str1)
lis2=combi(str2)
print max(set(lis1).intersection(set(lis2)),key=len)
```

**output:**

```
'sBagelS
```

Answer (score 0):

See

[String similarity metrics in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471153/string-similarity-metrics-in-python)

or checkout the simhash module:

http://bibliographie-trac.ub.rub.de/browser/simhash.py