# How to calculate word similarity with lists of words

Tags: nlp, spacy, cosine-similarity

Supposing I have three lists which contains words of different categories (database attributes):

```
products = ['price','quantity','vendor','name']
customers = ['age','location','name','gender']
employee = ['office','title','manager']
```

Now I have a phrase such as 'product name' which I want to classify them into one of the categories above. Is there any tools where I can calculate the similarity of the phrases with words in the three lists? This is under the assumption that I don't have a large training data sets (only small samples as shown in example above)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1471303/5010157]

if you are using php similar_text function will do.